# Swift variable with both 'get' and 'didSet'

Tags: swift, swift3, didset

I'm trying to have a swift 3 Date variable that takes action when it's set.  Part of that action is to call a function in the class to handle side effects.

The problem I'm running into is that method is also called from elsewhere, and part of what it does is set that same date variable.  That means I end up with a loop as the setter calls the function, which calls the setter.

I thought I'd have a separate backing store and then implement both a 'get' and a 'didSet' but that's apparently not allowed.

How do I work around this?

Comment: So setting the date calls a function, and calling that function sets the date? Then you might have to change your design. – Why do you think that get+didSet is not allowed? Why would that solve your problem? – Seeing the concrete code might help.

Comment: I added an optional `calledFromSetter` parameter that defaults to false, and I only set it now if that's false.  Not great, but seems like it will work.